# MSVS 2015 Profile Guided Optimization - Deploy Instrument Build on Various Machines

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, profiling, compiler-optimization

I would like to perform the following:

- Build a instrumented PGO exe using MSVS 2015 IDE
- Copy the generated exe along with its .pgd file to several other machines
- Run the exe from the command line on those machines.  Note these machines do not have the MSVS compiler on them.

Currently, I can only run the exe on the machine that I compiled it on and only through the IDE option Build->Profile Guided Optimization->Run Instrumented/Optimized Application.  If I try to run it through the command line (on any of the machines), I get the following error:

The application was unable to start correctly (0xc00007b)

Could someone please let me know if what I am trying to do is possible and the steps to make it work if it is?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To get the PGO instrumented version to run on the remote machines, I had to install the MSVS 2015 redistributable package as well as use the correct pgort140.dll.  On my local machine I had the following versions:

- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\pgort140.dll (49 KB)
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\amd64\pgort140.dll (55 KB)
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\arm\pgort140.dll (49 KB)

The one from \bin was causing the error to occur.  I had to use the dll from \bin\amd64 to get my exe to run, so I copied this version to my remote machines.